# getting contents from a .dmg or .img file

Tags: filesystems, mount, disk-image

I have a `.dmg` file meant for Mac, I'm trying to get the contents from it (it's Microsoft Project Manager, if that matters) but I can't figure out what to do. I've made a `.img` copy using `dmg2img`, and I've tried mounting the `.img` using `mount -o loop`, but I get this error:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0, missing
codepage or helper program, or other error
```

when I type file SDM.dmg, I get this:

```
SDM.dmg: zlib compressed data
```

and on the .img version:

```
SDM.img: DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0xee, start-CHS (0x3ff,254,63),
end-CHS (0x3ff,254,63), startsector 1, 39259 sectors, extended partition table (last)
```

Is mount the wrong command to use? Is there something else I need to do before mounting it?

Comment: Welcome to Unix.stackexchange! I recommend you [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This [link](http://eastmanreference.com/how-to-work-with-dmg-files-on-linux/) might help. First, decompress the file using `7z`:

```
7z x image.dmg
```

Then, mount it with:

```
sudo mount -t hfsplus foo.hfs /path/to/dir
```

I also found [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/38122/642784) post related to the same file type and opening it on linux

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be [preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259), and provide the link for reference

Comment: The links worked, I had to use 7zip to extract the files, then mount the .hfs file. Thank you!

Comment: @StephenRauch Your comment appears to say that the essential parts should be somewhere else (By having the word “here” as a hyperlink). It is only when we traverse the link that we get the meaning of your comment. Thus making your comment an un-example, of what you are saying.

Answer (score 1):

After converting the `.dmg` to `img` through `dmg2img` , you can mount the `img` file as follows:

```
mkdir /mnt/img_mnt
mount -t hfsplus your_file.img /mnt/img_mnt
```

Some packages need to be installed to easily manage `img` files .

e,g: On debian based distro you should install [`hfsplus`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/hfsplus), [`hfsprogs`](https://packages.debian.org/fr/jessie/hfsprogs) packages.

On Rhel : [`kmod-hfsplus`](https://elrepo.org/tiki/kmod-hfsplus)

Comment: I'm using Debian. I tried your solution, but even with the hfsplus and hfsprogs packagers, I still got the same error:
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0, missing
codepage or helper program, or other error